# ¿Manera correcta de ejecutar una función después de otra?

Tags: jquery

La siguiente función muestra una div por 1 segundo, luego la hace desaparecer y mediante un .animate que hace nada, ejecuta otra función después de medio segundo:

```js
muestra_reportes();

function muestra_reportes(){
    $(".reporte").show().delay(1000).fadeOut("slow").animate({left:'0'}, 500, function(){
      console.log("adsasd");
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="reporte" hidden>reportando</div>
```

Esto funciona bien, pero no me parece correcto usar un .animate falso para hacerlo.

Cuál sería la forma correcta de conseguir lo mismo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con un Promise, de la siguiente manera:

```
 $(".reporte").show().delay(1000).fadeOut("slow").promise().done(function() {
   //codigo de tu funcion
});
```

[+Info](http://rlbisbe.net/2015/04/26/explicando-promises-de-javascript-con-un-ejemplo-simple/)

Comment: muchas gracias :D